# What are the properties of $\Re f(x)$ for an analytical function $f$ if $\Im f(x)\ge 0 \forall x\in\mathbb R_0^+$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Background: In Electrodynamics, the scalar [permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) $\epsilon(\omega)$ relates the [Electric displacement field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) $\vec D$ to the electric field $\vec E$ as $\vec D=\epsilon\vec E$ when assuming a linear, isotropic medium. Causality requires that in time-space the Fourier transform $\tilde\epsilon(t)$ must vanish for $t<0$ (i.e. the future cannot influence $\vec D$), resulting in $\epsilon(\omega)$ being analytic and that the [Kramers-Kronig relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relation) (basically using the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)) can be used to relate the real and imaginary parts of $\epsilon$. The imaginary part describes absorption and must thus not be negative<sup>1</sup>, does this put any additional restraints on $\Re \epsilon$?

So in summary:

> For $\epsilon(\omega)$ analytical (because the Fourier transform $\tilde\epsilon(t)$ vanishes for $t<0$) and $\forall\omega>0:\Im\epsilon(\omega)\ge0$, what are properties of $\Re\epsilon(\omega)$ for $\omega>0$?

<sup>1)</sup> or positive, depending on convention as in whether the time dependence is $e^{+i\omega t}$ or $e^{-i\omega t}$

---

**edit** also, since $\vec E$ and $\vec D$ are real valued in time-space, $\epsilon(-\omega)=\epsilon(\omega)^*$

Comment: When you write $\epsilon(-w) = \epsilon(w)^*$, does $z^*$ denote complex conjugation?  for what values of $w$ does that hold? Finally, do you know anything about the growth/decay/asymptotic expansion of $\epsilon(w)$ as $|w| \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Sam yes, I mean complex conjugation. Is there some different convention I should use? This hold for all real $\omega$ and there is no a priori knowledge about complex $\omega$ involved. For $\omega\to\infty$, $\epsilon \to \epsilon_\infty$ being a constant.

Comment: somehow I didn't see your follow-up comment.  If $\epsilon$ is entire (analytic over the whole complex plane), and $|\epsilon(w)| \rightarrow \epsilon_\infty$ as $|w| \rightarrow \infty$, then by Liouville's theorem, $\epsilon(w) = \epsilon_\infty$.  Or did you mean that $\epsilon(w) \rightarrow \epsilon_\infty$ only as $|w| \rightarrow \infty$ along the real axis?  (I normally use $\bar z$ to denote the complex conjugate of $z$, but I have seen $z^*$ also used on occasion.)

Comment: @SamLisi: I only mean real valued positive $\omega\to\infty$. A constant $\epsilon(\omega)$ is definitely not the case, so nothing about $|\omega|\to\infty$ in general can be stated